# git “uncheckout” by 'reset --hard' does not produce expected results

Tags: git

I mistakenly created a remote branch (MY-12345-own-branch), then did a checkout on it. So, if I do `git branch --list` I see:

```
* Team_Branch_01
MY-12345-own-branch 
master
```

I would like to delete ("uncheckout") MY-12345-own-branch, so that I remain with:

```
* Team_Branch_01
master
```

However, when I perform:

```
git reset --hard origin/MY-12345-own-branch
git branch --list
```

Nothing appears to have changed -- I am still getting:

```
* Team_Branch_01
MY-12345-own-branch 
master
```

Why?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command to delete a branch:

```
git branch -d <branch_name>
```

If the branch has not been merged, use

```
git branch -D <branch_name>
```